# How to Loop through Json with SwiftyJson

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

how can I extract all values with key "text" in below json file using SwiftyJson? this is a response from Microsoft cognitive services text recognition.

```
{
"language": "de",
"textAngle": 0,
"orientation": "Up",
"regions": [
    {
        "boundingBox": "353,597,1926,1277",
        "lines": [
            {
                "boundingBox": "1091,597,410,93",
                "words": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1091,604,106,84",
                        "text": "Ka"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1210,597,291,93",
                        "text": "uflond"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boundingBox": "1122,861,358,89",
                "words": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1122,866,174,84",
                        "text": "Kauf"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1314,865,21,85",
                        "text": "I"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1348,861,132,87",
                        "text": "and"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boundingBox": "948,982,649,81",
                "words": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "948,986,398,77",
                        "text": "Schwabenp"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1359,984,19,74",
                        "text": "I"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1393,986,131,69",
                        "text": "atz"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1546,982,51,74",
                        "text": "LI"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "boundingBox": "944,1088,665,80",
                "words": [
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "944,1089,220,79",
                        "text": "70563"
                    },
                    {
                        "boundingBox": "1210,1088,399,75",
                        "text": "Stutt
```

the json file is much bigger and there is a lot of values with key "text" with different depth and I do not know how should I loop through the entire Json body! 
thanks for your help

Comment: If you are using Swift 4, we'd recommend you to use Codable. If not, you have to understand the structure of the JSON. It's not that complicate, it's just a dictionary at top level, which has a key regions which value is an Array of Dictionaries, etc. Do it step by step if necessary. So, did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Conform all of your objects to `Codable`, then just dig down as appropriate once you've instantiated instances, e.g. with a `TextDto` wrapper class:

```
class TextDto: Codable {
    let language: String
    let textAngle: Int
    let orientation: String
    let regions: [Region]

    init(language: String, textAngle: Int, orientation: String, regions: [Region]) {
        self.language = language
        self.textAngle = textAngle
        self.orientation = orientation
        self.regions = regions
    }
}

class Region: Codable {
    let boundingBox: String
    let lines: [Line]

    init(boundingBox: String, lines: [Line]) {
        self.boundingBox = boundingBox
        self.lines = lines
    }
}

class Line: Codable {
    let boundingBox: String
    let words: [Word]

    init(boundingBox: String, words: [Word]) {
        self.boundingBox = boundingBox
        self.words = words
    }
}

class Word: Codable {
    let boundingBox, text: String

    init(boundingBox: String, text: String) {
        self.boundingBox = boundingBox
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

Once you have your `TextDto` from the api, you can loop over all `lines` and `words` with `.forEach {}` closures or `for...in` loops as you see fit

Comment: If you adopt `Codable` you can delete all `init` methods. Those are not used by `Codable` anyway. And use classes only if you really need reference semantics.

Comment: True, but I did not know this guy's use-case (there is no way to infer that from what information he provided) - he could just use `Struct`s if that's more appropriate.